# how can we give hyperlink in zendfrom?

Tags: zend-framework, hyperlink, zend-form, smarty

In my smarty template..i used for hyperlink like this

{{node id="performance-contract-add"}}here{{/node}}

How can i write it in zend form?

Regads
kiran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Zend Forms** are used to create HTML forms for example `<input>, <select>` & etc.

Zend Framework by default uses Views to render HTML. It's plain PHP & HTML so link in zend framework can be created simply like that. `<a href="performance-contract-add">here</a>` placed in .phtml file. You can also make Smarty to work with Zend Framework

On other hand you may want to create custom decorators to make such link in **Zend Form** for example:

```
<?php
$foo = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('name');
$foo->setLabel('Name')
    ->setDescription('<a href="#">Link</a>')
    ->setDecorators(array(
        'ViewHelper',
        array('Description', array('escape' => false, 'tag' => false)),
        array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'dd')),
        array('Label', array('tag' => 'dt')),
        'Errors',
      ));
$form->addElement($foo);
```

You simply need to add  `array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'a'))` where you want in the stack.

And third option is to create a View Helper.